# Curl connection return Error

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I try to connect with SSL page per Curl with proxy. Unfortunately I get error:

> Proxy CONNECT aborted

When I try connect without proxy everything work properly.
What is the reason of that error?

```
const COOKIE_FILE = 'cookie.txt';
private $curlOptions = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0", // who am i
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,    // Disabled SSL Cert checks
    CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION  => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false
    //CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER       => array('Content-Type: text/html'),
    //CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION  => true,
    //CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      => 'cookie.txt',
    //CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     => 'cookie.txt'
);  
public function grab_page($site, $proxy=0){
$ch = curl_init();
if($proxy)
{
    $proxyCon = new Proxy();
    $proxyCon->setProxy();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxyCon->port);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxyCon->ip);
    //exit('s'.$proxyCon->ip.':'.$proxyCon->port);
}   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath(CurlService::COOKIE_FILE));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath(CurlService::COOKIE_FILE));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $this->curlOptions );    
ob_start();
return curl_exec ($ch);
ob_end_clean();
curl_close ($ch);
```

}

Comment: Are you using the following curl options in your setup? "CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH , CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE". You should probably give the related code if you want an adequate answer.

Comment: I added code. I my code I didn't use CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, but my proxy isn't need pass to use

Comment: `CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE` value 'HTTP' is not a valid option.  The value should be `0` for `CURLPROXY_HTTP` (or just use that constant).  And are you sure you're connecting to an HTTP proxy and not a SOCKS proxy?